# Disable permalinks on all pages and posts

Tags: permalinks

As I am using the JSON API, the permalinks don't make sense. My site URLs are totally different to the ones generated by the permalinks, so this is likely to confuse the client.

Is there any way I can disable permalinks on pages and on the default post type? I was able to do it on custom post types by specifying `'public' => false` but how do I make this change site-wide? Even the media pages have a permalink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WP 4.4, there is a hook you can use to edit default arguments for registered post types:

`register_post_type_args` [(view in context on trac)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php#L408)

If you're wanting to remove the permalink/slug from the edit post/page screens but not remove posts from the admin menu itself, setting `public => false` and `show_ui => true` should do that.

```
function remove_from_public( $args, $post_type ) {

    $args['public'] = false;
    $args['show_ui'] = true;

    // some other common uses:
    //$args['show_in_rest'] = false;
    //$args['rewrite']  = false;
    //$args['rest_base'] = false;

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'remove_from_public', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

I use `PHP_INT_MAX` just to kick it to the bottom of the hook to overwrite anything that may be getting called there.

Comment: Hi, I have a question regarding this. When I set `public` to false, it does indeed disable the permalink in the admin. However this also has a side effect in Advanced Custom Fields, in that it does not appear in the "post type" dropdown. Do you know if there is any other way to disable the permalinks?

Comment: hmmm... yeah, that would be expected. I wonder if there is a clean way to remove that filter (or add one separately) depending on admin screen. My worry is that it is too late to do so (or that it won't get set back). Something like using `$pagenow` or `get_current_screen()` to check for an ACF basename. Basically flip it `true` so ACF can use it, then `false` everywhere else. I'd have to think about it further though, something doesn't seem right about that approach.